# I need to stack the multiple x-y data one above the other with an offset

Tags: python, matplotlib, offset

I want my plot to as shown in the figure [XRD results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxLwn.png). I am trying to write a python code, which inputs all the data from '.xy' file extension of a particular directory. I am getting two plots overlapped over each other. I want an y-offset between these plots [Overlapping data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1vZW.png).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import os

px=[]
py=[]
for h in os.listdir(r'\\my directory')
    if h.endswith(".xy"):
        
        
        #print(m)
        x = []
        y = []
        f = open(h, "r")
        for i in f:
            row=i.split()
            x.append(row[0])
            y.append(row[1]) 
        
        for j in range(0, len(x)):
                x[j]=float(x[j])

        for j in range(0, len(y)):
                y[j]=float(y[j])
    
        px.append(x)
        py.append(y)
            
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.plot(px[i],py[i])
```

I tried to add a constant value to all of my y axis data, but it changes the shape of the plots depending on the offset. I am new to python. please bear with me.

Comment: What does "Does an" mean in the title?

Comment: Can you please show a [mre] of the problem you observed when trying to add offsets to the data?

Comment: Sorry for the bad title, I missed deleting "Does an".

Comment: You can still delete it by clicking [edit].

Comment: The solution by Andrew and gboffi was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I am new to StackOverflow, I just figured out! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be certain, but it looks like you want something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import os
import numpy as np

# Adjust the values in y_offsets as needed, this controls the spacing between plots
y_offsets = np.linspace(0, 25, len(os.listdir(r'\\my directory')))

px=[]
py=[]
# Use zip here to make the data from each file offset by the specified amount
for h, y_off in zip(os.listdir(r'\\my directory'), y_offsets):
    if h.endswith(".xy"):
        
        
        #print(m)
        x = []
        y = []
        with open(h, "r") as f: #closes the file when finished
            for i in f:
                row=i.split()
                x.append(row[0])
                y.append(row[1]) 
        
        for j in range(0, len(x)):
                x[j] = float(x[j])

        for j in range(0, len(y)):
                y[j] = float(y[j])+y_off # add y_off here, to shift all the y positions
    
        px.append(x)
        py.append(y)
            
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.plot(px[i],py[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your problem

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
 
x = np.linspace(0, 6.28, 629) 
y = np.sin(x)*np.exp(-0.8*x)                                                      

for n in range(5): 
    plt.plot(x, y+n) 
plt.yticks([]) ; plt.show()
```

gives me

[image]

as expected.

Could you please *explain in detail* what went wrong so that we may possibly help you?